# About android calender view

Tags: android

Is there a code realization for this widget (if exists)? Is it a native SDK widget or just design pattern?
[image]

Comment: What's the problem??You are facing @sanjay :)

Comment: Its simple sanjay.. First of all you have to find out current date with day of week according to that you have to fix them on the 7 images or button in yours top of the screen..And for the circular green and blue image...you have to use dynamic progess bar which have circular view..Try these tips and than if there any other problem than ping me in the same message chain'

Comment: brother dates are not fixed...dates are horizontally scrolable..

Comment: You can use the gridview which can acts as the horizontal listview...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that an exact implementation like that existed. You might have to build yours. However Square has a pretty neat Android Calendar library, [android-times-square](https://github.com/square/android-times-square) as does the [SDK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html), albeit not being an exact copy of your picture shows.